# Don't know how to start this program - bar chart for production using loops

Tags: c++

Normally I wouldn't do this, but I need some major help. I don't even know where to begin with this code.  It is supposed to have an output of:

```
What is the production of Plant 1 (000's)? 6
What is the production of Plant 2 (000's)? 4

                             PRODUCTION (000'S)
                    0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8
                    |---|---|---|---|---|---|---|---|
        Plant 1     *************************
        Plant 2     *****************
```

I know that it isn't good practice to ask someone for this much help, but I am on my wits end and have hit a wall.  Any help would be greatly appreciated

This is what I have, I know it's wrong and probably not even close

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()

{

cout<<"What is the production of Plant 1 (000's)? ";
int plant1;
cin>>plant1;
cout<<"What is the production of Plant 1 (000's)? ";
int plant2;
cin>>plant2;
cout<<"                      PRODUCTION (000's)"<<endl;;
cout<<"              0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8"<<endl;
cout<<"              |---|---|---|---|---|---|---|---|"<<endl;
cout<<"Plant 1";


for (int i=0; i<=plant1; i++)
{   
    cout<<"*";
}
cout<<"Plant 2";
    for (int j=0; j<=plant2; j++)
    {
    cout<<"*";
    }

cout<<endl;
return 0;
}
```

Comment: It would be in your best interests to at least attempt to solve the problem and include your attempt when asking a question.

Comment: I did, but it's ugly. I'll add it to the post.

Comment: build a string of "*" whose length is proportional to the inputs.  You need to scale the * by #characters between tick marks on your axis.  You are not that far off.

Comment: What do you think is wrong with your code? It looks like you are missing a `cout << endl;` after your first for loop.

Comment: The * only goes out the amount its given, not to the actual 6 or 4 mark, I also need Plant 1 and Plant 2 to be before the **

Comment: @ OldProgrammer I don't quite know how to do this. I am a beginner at c++ and having a hard time grasping it

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
cout<<"Plant 1";

for( int i = 0 i < 6 ; i++) cout<<" ";
for (int i=0; i<=plant1; i++)
{   
    cout<<"*";
}
cout<<endl<<"Plant 2";
for( int i = 0 i < 6 ; i++) cout<<" ";
    for (int j=0; j<=plant2; j++)
    {
    cout<<"*";
    }

cout<<endl;
```

Rest of the part remains same.